# Idling on windows logon screen to allow SSD to recover free space?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, trim

[On this page](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_set_up_Windows_on_a_VERTEX), the very last paragraph states

```
"For use within windows 7 there is absolutely no maintenance needed apart from 
allowing the machine to idle at the login screen for a few hours each week, 
this allows the garbage collection time to recover the drive and free up space 
TRIM has not been able to deal with. "
```

Is this true? My Windows7 automatically logs me in.

My new SSD is an Intel 510 (120G).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not necessary for your SSD. The [link](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_set_up_Windows_on_a_VERTEX) you posted only applies to the relatively old OCZ Vertex SSD, and its specific garbage collector. Your Intel 510 SSD natively [supports TRIM](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4202/the-intel-ssd-510-review/13), which should be sufficient to prevent performance degradation over time.

Intel's [SSD Toolbox](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455) software has an "optimise SSD" feature, but this should not be needed if you use Windows 7 and the Microsoft AHCI driver (see [this PDF](http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/intel_ssd_toolbox_frequently_asked_questions.pdf) for details).

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection happens when the computer is idle, but it wants to be "very" idle, as read/writes to the ssd means that GC cannot proceed.

When at the login screen, you can be certain that at least there are no userspace applications running, which tend to send lots of read-writes to the disk.

If you close all your apps, you can probably get it close enough to give gc a chance to get on with it, but the best chance is being logged out.